# How to Clear the text-box to enter a new value when a operator is Clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, buttonclick

**This is a Basic calculator Program** 
I am not able to clear text-box.

```
   protected void Button_Click(object sender, Event-args e)
    {
        if ((Result.Text == "0") || (operation_pressed))
            Result.Text = String.Empty;
 **//Here it should initialize when a value is 0 or when a operator is Clicked**
  ** //But the value in text-box is not clear even a operator is clicked**
          Button b = (Button)sender;
        Result.Text = Result.Text + b.Text;
    }     
  protected void Operator_Click(object sender, Event-args e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        operation = b.Text;
        value = Double.Parse(Result.Text);
        operation_pressed = true;
    }
```

Comment: How you manager the operation_pressed  value ? could you put all the page code, maybe you operation_pressed in the Page_Load event.

Answer (score 0):

Because text clear logic is placed in `Button_Click` event. Yo have few options to fix this issue.

1. Move logic inside button click to `Operator_Click`
2. Else separate clearing part with new `Method` and invoke from both functions after setting `operation_pressed` value.
3. Other option is to explicitly call/triggeer button event.

Comment: Can i use Result.Text = String.Empty; to clear the text-box ? is there any other way to clear the text-box?

Comment: That should work, alternatively you could also use `Result.Clear()`

Comment: I checked Result.Clear(). I don't know why it is not working. It is showing error sign if i use Clear method.

Comment: I don't see any reason it is not working, it is [supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Its saying text-box doesn't contain definition for Clear. you are missing assembly or reference.

Comment: Try rebuilding the project, if not try reopening solution.